# CloudKit: switch container environment from Development to Production

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cloudkit

I'm building a test tool to verify content in CloudKit, but I want to be able to select the container's environment.

On iOS, you can select either the "Development" or the "Production" environment when you export your app for ad hoc testing, but you don't have that option on OS X. It always points to the "Development" environment.

Anyone knows, if there is a programmatically way to set or select what container environment you want to work with, either on OS X or iOS?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Might be worth switching "sandbox" to "development" in your title, since that's the correct term. I saw another SO question where they said to add com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment to the Entitlements with a value of "Production". This caused a code signing error. :-(

Comment: Please let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the entitlements file, add in the row of `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment` and you can switch the value of that back and forth between `Development` and `Production`.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. When you launch the app it kills it with a code signing error.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. My issue was that I wasn't deploying the Dev -> Prod environments while using CloudKit.

Comment: This works in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be a bit late for those who posted but for others with the same problem, in the entitlement file change the `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment`from `Development` to `Production` Then delete your app from your device so you get a clean build. When you run it, it should work. The key is to have a clean build.

Comment: This should be a comment or edit to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36870837/4957508) that says 90% of the same thing.

Comment: Its the 10% that developers are missing and saying it doesn't work. The clean build

Comment: As mentioned above, very important to delete app to get clean build.  Otherwise, app will continue to work with previous container (development or production).  Also, error may result from changing entitlement file (indicating change during build is not supported). Use Product, Clean Build Folder to eliminate error.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: this changed in later versions of CloudKit, please ignore this and see the accepted answer.

No, there is no way to do that.

While you can access the same container as your iOS app, you can only access the "Development" environment until you export your application as a Mac App to the App Store (which is probably not your goal for a test tool).

The App Store application again would only be able to access the "Production" environment.

There is no other API to access CloudKit containers in a specific environment.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can indeed force the app to use the Production CloudKit environment by following the instructions in the answer by @snagra.

Comment: Note that my answer was from 2015 and CloudKit improved a lot since. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an extended plist file, iOS Extended.plist, so the answer above did not work when I put the value for the key and value in the iOS.plist.

But for those with the extended plist, make sure to put it there(only there is necessary), and delete the app, clean the build, and run it